# Does Hibernate sort alphanumeric with special characters correctly?

Tags: java, hibernate, sorting

For example, if the Order in criteria is ascending and if we have two names like follows:

- _zname_9
- 1_aname_

I get an output like:

- _zname_9
- 1_aname_

But the expected output is:

- 1_aname_
- _zname_9

Am I missing something? Please note that I dont want to escape special characters while setting the criteria.

Does Hibernate sort wrongly?

Comment: I'd say it depends on the collation order for your table/database.

Comment: Hibernate does not sort, your underlying database does.

Comment: thanks for clarifying, i shall check with the underlying database

Comment: @AmitParashar, so will the result of sorting depend on type of database? For eg: sorted result from postgres could differ from sorted result from sqlite?

Comment: @a3.14_Infinity, Yes.